# Trying to debug an LLVM pass with gdb , gdb says no debugging symbols found ?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, llvm

I want to debug my LLVM pass with gdb. I've built llvm with the default make so debugging info should be added.

When I do gdb user/bin/opt it says:

Reading symbols from opt...(no debugging symbols found)...done.

This shouldn't happen because according to the LLVM documentation , 'opt has a lot of debugging info'

http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#debughints

Is this because I haven't built LLVM correctly ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It has debugging info as in "you can make it output the LLVM-IR before and after the passes", and various other such things. If you build a debug build of LLVM, you can also debug inside llvm code. But also, you probably are most interested in your pass, which is hopefully compiled with debug symbols. Use `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` to build llvm with debug symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the complete way to do this : ->

First make sure LLVM is compiled  with the debug options  which is basically the default setting. If you didn't compile LLVM with non-default options then your current build should be fine.

All LLVM passes are run using LLVM's opt (optimizer) tool.  Passes are compiled into shared object files i.e LLVMHello.so file in build/lib and then loaded by the opt tool.  To debug or step through the pass we have to halt LLVM before it starts executing the .so file because there is no way to put a break point in a shared object file. Instead , we can put a break in the code BEFORE it invokes the pass.

We're going to put a breakpoint in llvm/lib/IR/Pass.cpp

Here's how to do it :

Step 1 ->  Navigate to build/bin and open terminal and type  gdb opt . If you compiled llvm with the debug symbols added then gdb will take some time to load debugging symbols , otherwise gdb will say  loading debugging symbols ...(no debugging symbols found).

Step 2 -> Now , we need to set a break point at the   void Pass::preparePassManager(PMStack &) method in Pass.cpp . This is probably the first(or one of the first) methods involved in loading the pass. 
You can do this by by typing   break llvm::Pass::preparePassManager  in terminal.

Step 3 -> Running the pass . I have a bitcode file called trial.bc and the same LLVMHello.so pass so I run it with

run -load ~/llvm/build/lib/LLVMHello.so  -hello < ~/llvmexamples/trial.bc > /dev/null

gdb will now stop at Pass:: preparePassManager and from here on we can use step and next to trace the execution.